# Структура программы и ее компоненты на C#

Tags: c#

Я не уверен корректно ли я задал вопрос,хочу узнать правильно ли я понимаю следующее.

Программа – это некая сборка, которая состоит из пространств имен, а те в свою очередь из классов. Сборка – это физический элемент, хранящийся  на диске. В Visual Studio, в обозреватели решений, решения и есть сборки, а проекты этих сборок – это пространства имен? И хотелось бы узнать может ли несколько таких решений компилироваться в программу, то есть состоять из нескольких сборок.

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить уж очень простым языком и опустить некоторые неточности, то

Сборка - это файл с кодом (классами), выглядит как имя_файла.dll.

Программа - это EXE файл (исполняемый файл) с классами (то есть с кодом), который можно запустить через проводик windows просто дважды кликнув по нему.

Разница между программой и сборкой только в том, что программу можно запустить кликнув по ней, сборку нельзя. Чтобы запустить код из сборки, нужна программа, которая на эту сборку будет ссылаться.

Простарнство имен - название говорит само за себя. Вот вы создаете класс MyClass, и какой то вася создает класс MyClass, и может ещё миллион человек создают классы с названием MyClass. И чтобы все эти классы можно было бы испольщовать вместе, придумали пространства имен. Это как имя и фамилия, где имя - это имя класса, а фамилия - простанство имен. Вы можете знать 10 Вась, но при этом различать их по фамилии. Но вот если будут 2 Васи с одинаковой фамилией, в пастпортном столе начнется путаница. Потому вы не можете в одно простанство имен засунуть 2 одинаковых класса. Простанство имен не привязано ни к сборке, ни к программе ни к проекту. Вы можете создавать сборки с любым количеством пространств имен в них, или использовать единое пространство имен для всех сборок. По сути, вы можете давать любые фамилии своим классам до тех пор, пока имя и фамилия класса уникальны в вышей программе и во всех сборках, на которые ваша программа ссылается.

В Visual Studio есть решения, решение делится на проекты. Проект может быть программой, сборкой или чем то ещё (например, есть проект баз данных).

Вы, для простоты, в своей голове можете считать, что каждый проект - это в итоге либо программа, либо сборка. Каждый проект компилируется отдельно, у каждого проекта что то своё на выходе, но проекты могут зависеть друг от друга. Например, вы можете иметь решение, где один проект-программа, и он ссылается на несколько проектов-сборок.

Чтобы объединить несколько проектов во что то одно, используется решение. Решение - это просто объединение проектов. У самого решения, как такового, на выходе нет ничего. Компиляция решения означает просто компиляцию каждого проекта, что в это решение входит.

Comment: Правильнее сказать не "программа", а "приложение" (указать в скобках или сделать полную замену). Так-то программа, это просто код, выполняющий какую-либо задачу. Код относится к программе, как набор предложений и тексту. Да и ваша "сборка" называется библиотекой... А сборкой называют *любой* скомпилированный IL код... Называйте вещи своими именами.

Comment: Я старался ответить языком автора. Того, что я написал, вполне достаточно, чтобы начать понимать что происходит. Все остальные уточнения на текущем уровне автора особо смысла не имеют. Я же не документацию тут переписывал, а попробовал пояснить простыми  (хотя и не точными терминами) словами.

Comment: Ну не знаю... Всё же исправить или уточнить стоит, ведь дальше может возникнуть путаница. А если он он найдёт класс `Assembly`, то он будет думать, что это класс для приложений, хотя он работает и для либ. И да, когда я говорю либа, он тоже не будет понимать, про что я (только если он до этого на каком-нибудь C не программировал). Фраза "напишем программку" станет для него фразой "напишем приложение". И т. д. Лучше в сноске указать что есть что.

Comment: Так же я заметил, что вы не говорите про модули. Конечно модули сейчас не популярны, но ссылочку на доку я бы кинул.

Comment: @return с удовольствием почитаем ваш ответ (:

Comment: @return да, может имеет смысл добавить вторым ответом, ну и чтобы без пинг понга обойтись, можете просто добавить что считаете нужным прямо в мой ответ, я вам доверяю :)

Comment: А как одна сборка может содержать несколько пространств имен,если один проект в решение,к примеру,будущая сборка,и в одном проекте используется только одно пространство имен или нет?

Comment: @n_enrai49 пространство имён это просто синтаксический сахар. На самом деле пространство имён является частью имени типа. Например, `System.Windows.Window` – это *полное* имя типа `Window`, а `System.Windows` – пространство имён. Т. е. вы можете иметь сколько угодно пространств имён, но хорошим тоном считается 1-2 корневых пространства имён

Comment: @return, все равно не понимаю как, разве в решение один проект это не есть пространство имен,то есть сборка по итогу или приложение?

Comment: @n_enrai49 я ж говорил, что запутется... нет. проект создает 1 файл с скомпилированной программой, а пространство имён это пространство имён, т. е. часть полного имени типа

Comment: @return то есть сборка это, если можно так сказать,компилируем, это и есть само решение чтоли

Comment: @return ваши пояснения тоже не помогли :) автору надо всего лишь внимательный прочитать мой ответ, там есть про пространства имен.

Comment: @tym32167 просто надо было всё своими словами назвать, я уверен, что если автор нашёл этот сайт, то он на 100% умный и сможет понять ваши "мегасложные" определения.

Comment: @n_enrai49, в одном проекте может быть несколько пространств имён, несколько проектов могут иметь одно пространство имён. Вообщем, нет теоретических ограничений на соответствие одного к другому.

Comment: @n_enrai49, на практике вообщем-то это тоже так. Но всё-таки с некоторыми оговорками. В одном проекте, если и используются несколько пространств имён то в таком стиле `MyProject`, `MyProject.DataLayer` и т.д. А вот использование одного пространства имён встречается в разных проектах встречается даже в самом фреймворке.

Answer (score 2):

Проект – это просто папка (вы можете через проводник залезть туда и в этом убедиться). Проект, в случае с C#, обладает 1-м св-вом – он может брать и компилировать файлы с C# кодом. Конечно, это делает не сама VS, а компилятор, но она является "мостиком" м-ду "низкоуровневым" компилятором и высокоуровневой кнопкой «Собрать»/«Запустить».

Так вот, продукт компиляции называется сборкой. Сборка – это просто контейнер типов. В C# сборка может иметь физических 2 вида (2 расширения файла) (Windows): `.exe` и `.dll`. Файлы `.exe` – это запускаемые (executable) *приложения* (applications), а файлы `.dll` – это переносимая (portable) *библиотека* (library). Библиотеки созданы для того, чтобы их включать в приложения и не переписывать код, давно уже написанный. А приложения этот код используют при своём запуске.

Так что же такое это пространство имён? Пространство имён создано с такой же целью, что и папки: их задача создать иерархию типов, для более простого восприятия, чтобы все-все типы не толпились у вас под рукой. Пространство имён – это часть имени типа. Например, у полного имени типа `System.Int32` (в C# просто `int`) `System` – пространство имён, а `Int32` – короткое имя типа. Ещё больше примеров:

```
System
├ Int32
├ Diagnostics
│ └ Process
├ Windows
│ ├ Window
│ ├ UIElement
│ └ Controls
│   └ Button
└ Collections
  └ Hashtable
```

Из этого понятного дерева типов в реальности формируется обычный список:

```
System.Int32
System.Diagnostics.Process
System.Windows.Window
System.Windows.UIElement
System.Windows.Controls.Button
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

Вот в таком виде (в виде списка), мы и используем типы:

```cs
System.Span<System.Byte> span = default;
ref System.Byte @ref = ref System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal
    .GetReference(span);
```

Согласитесь, читать не возможно. Для этого добавили директиву `using`:

```cs
using System
```

Теперь нам не придётся постоянно писать `System.Byte`, а просто `Byte`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
⋮
Span<Byte> span = default;
ref Byte @ref = ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(span);
```

Вы не должны вникать в суть кода: объём кода и его читаемость стали в разы лучше.

Но тогда вы спросите: зачем нужны пространства имён, если мы их в коде почти-что явно не используем? Всё просто: есть 2 типа:

- `System.Windows.Controls.Button` – тип кнопки в WPF
- `System.Windows.Forms.Button` – тип кнопки в WinForms

И то и то кнопка, но у них будет происходить конфликт, который без пространств имён разрешить нормально никак не получиться.

Есть примеры и по-реалистичнее (но думаю вы поняли саму суть):

- `System.IO.Path`
- `System.Windows.Media.Path`

Осталось понять, что такое решение. Это ещё проще: это просто контейнер проектов. Вот и всё. Но у него также есть 1 св-во: он позволяет ссылаться (добавлять в зависимости в .NET Core) библиотеки ваших же проектов с автокомпиляцией.

Т. е. у вас есть какое-нибудь такое решение:

```
MySolution
├ MyApplication (C# WPF Application)┐
└ MyLibrary (C# Class Library)←─────┘
```

Как мы видим, в нашем решении есть 2 проекта: WPF приложение `MyApplication` и библиотека классов `MyLibrary`. При этом, наш проект `MyApplication` ссылается на проект `MyLibrary`, что позволяет ему использовать типы из нашей библиотеки. При этом, если мы попытаемся собрать `MyApplication`, то автоматически будет собрана и `MyLibrary`, т. к. мы на неё ссылаемся. Решение объединяет проекты в первую очередь по смыслу.

---

Сделаем короткий review всего вышесказанного:

- Решение – это контейнер проектов
- Проект – это папка
- Проекты в решении могут ссылаться друг на друга
- Проект C# – это проект (т. е. папка) с исходным кодом C#, который может брать и компилировать этот код в сборку
- Сборка – это контейнер типов
- Сборка может иметь физическую интерпретацию в виде `.exe` и `.dll` файлов
- Полное имя типа состоит из пространства имён и короткого имени типа
- Пространства имён созданы для иерархичности и избежания конфликтов
- Пространства имён можно <s>послать куда по-дальше</s> неявно использовать с помощью `using` <s>и забыть о них как о страшном сне</s>

---

ДОПИНг (ДОПолнительная ИНформация):

- [Решения и проекты в VS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
- [Типы проектов C#](https://professorweb.ru/my/programs/visual-studio/level2/2_5.php)
- [Компилятор C# (.NET Core)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet)
- [Компилятор C# (.NET Framework)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)
- [Рефлексия в .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) (опционально)
- [Сборки в .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/assembly/)
- [Пространства имён C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/)
- [Указание полных имён типов C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names)
- [Директива `using` С#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive)